# Writing raw prototype code to an rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

In most of the tutorials I have seen, whenever there is a requirement of add raw prototype code, the author uses application.js file. But in a huge application,writing the js code for the whole app in single file doesn't make sense. So what is the right way of doing it? Is it possible to write js code in different files and add it to my template based on my action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can create a js file for each of your view.  And include them appropriately.

application.js should only contains general purpose javascript function.

Comment: any source which I can refer to?

Comment: well i have this one: http://codefastdieyoung.com/2011/03/css-js-organization-best-practice/

Comment: It's just a matter of file organization.  You saw it does not make sense to put all your Javascript code inside a single file .js.  And i agree with you 100%.  It's like a java programmer who write an application in a single class called myApp ;-)  regards